# Skip cells in GridLayoutManager android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `RecycleViewer(GridLayoutManager)` in which **0,2,5,7** positions are fixed with `Custom images (relativeLayout converted to bitmap)`

I wanted to skip these **0,2,5,7** positions , because they already have `Custom images` **&** I wanted to fill the rest positions with the server images

**inside onBindViewHolder**

```
if (position == 0) {
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredHeight());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getDrawingCache());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            ...
        }
        if (position == 5) {
            ...
        }
        if (position == 7) {
            ...
        }

        if (position!=0 || position!= 2 || position!=5 || position!=7){
            ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageUrl(model.Images, imageLoader);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.im_profile_monuments);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bt_profile_addphoto);
       }
```

**But** the server images doesn't skip the **0,2,5,7** positions , it also gets displayed (technically behind my custom image)

Comment: Did you look at my answer?  The error in your code is very simple to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your last if statement is **always true**.

Here's how your incorrect statement works for **position 0**:

```
if (position!=0 || position!= 2 || position!=5 || position!=7) {
```

if position != 0 (false) OR position != 2 (**true**) - since the statement is **true** it executes - you don't want it to be true in this case because you don't want to execute if position is 0 or 2 or 5 or 7.

You would need to && the conditions if you want the imageloader to only happen for not 0 **and** not 2 **and** not 5 **and** not 7...

else if's would have been a much better choice for your conditionals.

But your code would be much simpler, faster, and easier to read if you used a switch statement.

```
switch(position) {
   case 0:
      ...
      break;
   case 2:
      ...
      break;
   case 5:
      ...
      break;
   case 7:
      ...
      break;
   default:
      ...
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `List` reference variable which you are populating from data which you are getting from the server and than it is set to the `Adapter`. (lets assume that you are getting 6 items from the server).

so your list has elements in following positions like this

```
list[ 0= "data",1= "data",2= "data",3= "data",4= "data",5= "data",6= "data"]
```

problem is that your adapter populates `gidview` with respective to the list you are providing which will not skip elements,

what you can do is, While making the `List` you can skip the positions where you want the adapter to skip, in this manner

```
list.add(0,null);

list.add(1, "add your data from the server for this position");

list.add(2,null);

list.add(3,"add your data from the server for this position");

list.add(4,"add your data from the server for this position");

list.add(5,null);

list.add(6,"add your data from the server for this position");

list.add(7,null);

list.add(8,"add your data from the server for this position");
```

and in your `onBindViewHolder` make some changes, when you get a null object from the list, you can set these values for that item

```
ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageUrl(model.Images, imageLoader);
ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.im_profile_monuments);
ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bt_profile_addphoto);
```

> Update

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mDefaultImages.length; i++) {

        photosModel = new ProfilePhotosModel(); 
        photosModel.Images = mDefaultImages[i];
        if (profilePhotosListData.size() == 0 || profilePhotosListData.size() == 1||profilePhotosListData.size() == 4||profilePhotosListData.size() == 6) {
            profilePhotosListData.add(null);
            profilePhotosListData.add(photosModel);
        }else {
            profilePhotosListData.add(photosModel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use a model like for (int i = 0; i < mDefaultImages.length; i++) {
                                    photosModel = new ProfilePhotosModel();                                 
                                    photosModel.Images = mDefaultImages[i];
                                    profilePhotosListData.add(photosModel);
                                }

Comment: how do I achieve that ?

Comment: @karthikkolanji, i have updated the answer that you can add the elements in such a way that you can skip 0,2,5,7. ......... as you are adding a null in the list you would have to check in the binder if the object is null if it is you would have to set predefined data

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
if (position == 0) {
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredHeight());
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getDrawingCache());
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
    else if (position == 2) {
        ...
    }
    else if (position == 5) {
        ...
    }
    else if (position == 7) {
        ...
    }

    else {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageUrl(model.Images, imageLoader);
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.im_profile_monuments);
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bt_profile_addphoto);
   }
```